# start redis-server with docker-compose up

Tags: python, docker, redis, docker-compose, pipenv

I use pipenv to start my application server and would like to start redis-server when the container spins up.

right now, I have to spin up a container and go inside of the container and run `redis-server` to start redis. I want to start everything with `docker-compose up`.

is there a way to do this ?

I have a docker-composer file like below

```
version: '3'

services:
  api:
    # docker run -d -p 8000:8000 data-tracker-backend pipenv run start 
    build: ./api
    command: pipenv run start
    image : data-tracker-backend
    volumes:
      - ./api:/api
    expose:
      - "8000"
```

Thank you

Comment: create one more service called redis-server and you can mention in your app-server `dependsOn` as redis, that way you spin up the redis (all other dependencies required for your appserver) and then spin up your app server.

Comment: The Docker documentation has several [Sample applications](https://docs.docker.com/samples/#sample-applications) and many of these are multi-container applications.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create another service for redis and make the first service i.e api dependent on the redis service.
Change your docker-compose.yml to something like this

```
version: '3'

services:
  api:
    build: ./api
    command: pipenv run start
    image : data-tracker-backend
    volumes:
      - ./api:/api
    expose:
      - "8000"
    depends_on:
      - redis-server

  redis-server:
    image: "redis:alpine"
    command: redis-server
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
```